# Delphi Froze when registering type library

Tags: delphi, com, types

I have created a few AUTOObjects using Delphi and its type library. It compiles without error, but when I tried to register it, Delphi froze, and doesn't return to normal. I have tried to register it in both Delphi 7 and 2006, but both get into the same problem. I tried to register a simple library in Delphi's demo, I am ruling out bad registry file,

There might be something wrong with my code, but I have no idea where, since it compiles well and I have not put any code in RegisterDLL.

Anyone had the same problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in one of unit there was a initialization code creates threads, now I have removed it, the library registers fine.

Answer (score 1):

Initialization sections of the units also get executed when registering a COM dll. Try registering outside of Delphi with tregsvr or regsvr32 and see if that works ok. You can also have those tools as a startup project and debug your dll while it gets registered.